# How to redirect from event handler in OctoberCMS plugin?

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I have registered a listener for 'rainlab.user.logout' in the boot event of my plugin.

```
public function boot()
{
    Event::listen('rainlab.user.logout', function ($controller) {
        return Redirect::to('https://www.google.com');
    });
}
```

It does nothing. I have confirmed the flow is reaching this block by using

```
header("Location: https://www.google.com");
exit;
```

in place of the return statement which gives an alert box saying **"error"** without the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Logout Ajax link's data attribute to redirect anywhere you want. check below example. [ **for this to work you need to add session component to your page** ]

check for more info : https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-user#documentation

```html
<a data-request="onLogout" 
   data-request-data="redirect: 'https://www.google.com'"
>
   Sign out
</a>
```

> Still if you want to use event to redirect user you can use below code. Note : its kind of hacky approach `not recommended but yes it works`.

```php
Event::listen('rainlab.user.logout', function ($controller) {
  $_POST['redirect'] = 'https://www.google.com';        
});
```

> **Why your approach is not working** [ Extra for understanding only ]
>
> Because in event handler they did not catch any data which you return from event, you are `returning Redirect` but in handler they don't catch it or receive it, this event `rainlab.user.logout` just fired and let you access `$user` object data nothing more. so your return statement has no effect on it.

**content** : plugins/rainlab/user/components/Session.php

```php
public function onLogout()
{
    $user = Auth::getUser();

    Auth::logout();

    if ($user) {
        Event::fire('rainlab.user.logout', [$user]);
        // ^ see, nothing is here which can accept your return redirect.
    }

    $url = post('redirect', Request::fullUrl());

    Flash::success(Lang::get('rainlab.user::lang.session.logout'));

    return Redirect::to($url);
}
```

if you have any doubt please comment.

Comment: The $_POST['redirect'] method worked like a charm. Thanks.